how to collapse rows multiple times in html css js
TO ACHIVE: freeze header, freeze first column and collapse row multiple times.
ALREADY ACHIVED: freeze header, freeze first column and collapse only one time.
MY CODE SO FAR:


</head>
<body>
<div class="table-container">
<table>
<thead class="freeze-header">
<tr>
<th class="freeze-col">Header 1</th>
<th>Header 2</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="parent-row">
<td class="freeze-col"><i class="fas fa-caret-right collapse-icon"></i> Row 1, Column 1</td>
<td>Row 1, Column 2</td>
</tr>
<tr class="collapse">
<td colspan="3">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr class="parent-row">
<td class="freeze-col"><i class="fas fa-caret-right collapse-icon"></i> Row 1.1, Column 1</td>
<td>Row 1.1, Column 2</td>
</tr>
<tr class="collapse">
<td colspan="3">
<table><tbody><tr>
<td>Row 1.1.1, Column 1</td>
<td>Row 1.1.1, Column 2</td>
</tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr>
<tr class="parent-row">
<td class="freeze-col"><i class="fas fa-caret-right collapse-icon"></i> Row 2, Column 1</td>
<td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
<td>Row 2, Column 3</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table></div>

<script>
    // JavaScript to handle collapse functionality
    document.querySelectorAll('.parent-row').forEach(function(row) {
        row.addEventListener('click', function() {
            var nextRow = row.nextElementSibling;
            if (nextRow && nextRow.classList.contains('collapse')) {
                nextRow.classList.toggle('show');
                row.querySelector('.collapse-icon').classList.toggle('fa-caret-right');
                row.querySelector('.collapse-icon').classList.toggle('fa-caret-down');
            }
        });
    });
</script>



How to achieve same as below image? thank you.
Layout to achieve
